# Line break a <label> with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple checkboxes in bootstrap columns that act as a filter for map markers.

I'm using an empty `<div>` element to display a colored square, then the actual checkbox, and last a `<label>` with the filter name.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="map-legend-box" style="background: #42bcf4"></div>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <label class="control-label checkbox-label-align">Some text here</label>
</div>
```

When the label contains a very long filter name, the label will be displayed on a second line, when I instead would like it to be displayed on the first, and then break to the second line if it doesn't fit in the first.

I've tried a different combination of `word-wrap` / `word-break` / `white-space` properties with CSS, but can't get it to work.

I've created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mAL9ahcYXkwq5w0HHZUD?p=preview) of how it is at the moment.

How do I get it to look like in the mockup picture below using CSS?

[image]

Comment: @Code Spirit has a good answer, I'd recommend staying away from flexbox as IE and Edge don't properly support it. Flexbox is amazing and should absolutely be supported everywhere, but until it is, don't rely on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move the `.map-legend-box` inside your `label` and position it `absolute`. Then add a little bit of `padding-left` to make room for your `.map-legend-box`.

```css
.row{
  max-width: 200px;
}

label{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.map-legend-box{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.box-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box-container * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    
    <label class="control-label checkbox-label-align">
      <div class="box-container">
        <div class="map-legend-box" style="background: #42bcf4"></div>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat aspernatur, eos harum dicta ullam quam, voluptatibus delectus debitis tenetur, possimus architecto temporibus laborum tempora blanditiis fugiat tempore illo ipsum labore.
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the checkbox?

Comment: Ive edited my snippet. Thought you want a custom checkbox. There are multiple solutions for it but for now I wrapped the checkbox and `.map-legend-box` inside `.box-container` to not set a position for each element.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I ended up using even though `flexbox` is available. The code must support IE10 which renders out the use of `flexbox`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex`. This will make the work real easy.

```css
.checkbox-container {
  width: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
}
#square {
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
label {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="checkbox-container">
    <div id="square" style="background: #42bcf4"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <label>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat aspernatur, eos harum dicta ullam quam, voluptatibus delectus debitis tenetur, possimus architecto temporibus laborum tempora blanditiis fugiat tempore.
  </label>
</div>
```